# Proving Two Groups are Isomorphic given Products are Isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $K,M,N$ be groups such that $K$ is finite and $K \times M$ is isomorphic to $K \times N$. Prove that $M$ and $N$ are isomorphic

My initial thoughts: I believe I should use induction on the order of $K$ because it is finite. I would then take $G=K_1H_1=K_2H_2$ with $K_1,H_1,K_2,H_2$ are all normal subgroups of $G$ such that $K_1 \cap H_1 = K_2 \cap H_2 = \{e\}$. Additionally, we take $K_1$ and $K_2$ are both isomorphic to $K$. Now take $M$ and $N$ such that $H_1$ is isomorphic to $M$ and $H_2$ is isomorphic to $N$. We then take $T_1=K_1 \cap H_2$ and $T_2=K_2 \cap H_1$.  I believe it might be easier to show that $K_1/T_1 \times K_2/T_2 \times H_1$ and $K_1/T_1 \times K_2/T_2 \times H_2$ are isomorphic.  My knowledge of quotient groups might be a little weak so I am stuck around here.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! This has been asked a few times before, but I can't find the ones on this site right now... Regardless, this is a theorem of Hirshon, and you can read more about it (and some generalizations) [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33589/stably-isomorphic-groups) ^_^

Comment: "I believe I should use induction on the order of $K$ because it is finite." For *finite* groups it is true, but not in general, see Bill's answer at the duplicate.